Why FindRoot needs 10 GB of memory to solve this nonlinear equation?
Can anybody explain to me why the following code fails to execute due to insufficient memory error,
and whether there is any way to overcome this problem?
F[x_, y_, g_] := x - (Exp[y] - Exp[-g y]);
y0 = 2 ArcSinh[x];
x = 10;
g = 10^10;
root = FindRoot[F[x, y, g], {y, y0}, 
                WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> ∞];

It seems that ca. 10 GB of memory is needed to get the correct result, but for me this is incomprehensible. What does the Newton method store in such a large amount?
Maybe this is a bug in FindRoot?
Leszek

I tried it in Mathematica version 14.1 on macos and it terminates flawlessly. But MaxMemoryUsed indeed reports that 10813808632 Bytes are used, which is roughly 10 GB. This is indeed weird. I think you should report this to Wolfram Support.

I tried tio.run it also bug on 12.0.1

Do you have an idea how big is E^(10^10) or how small is E^(-10^10)? Surely you need a lot of memory to handle numeric computations with such numbers.

Do you have an idea how big is E^(10^10) or how small is E^(-10^10)? Oooh. Good point. WorkingPrecision->50 should enforce 50-digit precision only. So storing the mantissa should not be the problem. However, storing the exponent would require $\log_2(\exp(10^10)) \approx 1.4427*10^10) bits. That is 1.8 gigabyte. Store a couple of these numbers and you are quickly at 10 gigabytes.

A reasonable way to overcome this problem is to remove the negligible term Exp[-g*y]. It doesn't affect the value of the solution and x - Exp[y]  == 0 is easy to solve both in Mma and by hand. If the neglected term is to be significant, you need more than 10^10 digits of working precision which is a lot. I killed it when it got to over 100GB and hadn't evaluated the function even once yet.

For me, N[Exp[-g*Log[10]], 50] takes almost 12 GB/84 sec and N[Exp[-g*2 ArcSinh[10]], 50] takes (well) under 100 MB/0.05 sec. Maybe not relevant, but it shows the arbitrary precision library can vary on similar inputs.

But it can also be done like this:
 x = 10;
 g = 10^10;
 FindRoot[Log[x] == Log[(Exp[y] - Exp[-g*y])], {y, 2*ArcSinh[x]}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 30, 
 AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]]

 (* {y -> 2.3025850929940456840179914546843642076011014886288} *)

Result instantly, memory consumption almost zero...

Thanks, this seems to help indeed. But I still don't understand why evaluation of Log[(Exp[y] - Exp[-gy])] turns out to require less memory than (Exp[y] - Exp[-gy]) itself. The latter expression, in my naive understanding, must be evaluated anyway, before Log of it is computed. Leszek

@Leszek But once its Log[] is evaluated, the memory holding it may be freed. It doesn't have to be kept around for subsequent calculations.

@Leszek Note that the solution is Log[10], that is, the solution to x == Exp[y], since at 50-digit precision, Exp[-g*y] is negligible.

Gazillion-digit solutions
The OP expressed interest in solving the equations for large g.
Solving via iteration
A couple of substitutions leads to an iterative solution:
$$x - (e^y - e^{-gy}) = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$x - (t - t^{-g}) = 0 \qquad (t=e^y)$$
$$z = (x + z)^{-g} \qquad (\,t=x+z,\ y=\log(x+z)\,)$$
So if $z_*$ is a fixed point of $f(z)=(x+z)^{-g}$, then $y=\log(x+z_*)$ is a solution of (1).
The iteration $z_{n+1}=f(z_n)$ converges rapidly to $z_*$ if $x >\mkern-4mu>1$ and $g >\mkern-4mu>1$; and the greater $x$ and $g$, the more rapid the convergence.
Example: g = 10^8
After four iterations, F = 0 to five hundred million digits. Each iteration adds roughly one hundred million digits.
foo = SessionTime[];

ClearAll[F];
F[x_, y_, g_] := x - (Exp[y] - Exp[-g*y]);

Clear[x, g, y, z];
tempfile = "/tmp/seq.mx";
iterFN = Function[z, (x + z)^-g];
x = 10;
g = 10^8;
"M0" -> MaxMemoryUsed[] // Echo;
rt(*=roots[0]*)= N[x^-g, 100];
CreateFile[tempfile, OverwriteTarget -> True];
"Rt" -> {MaxMemoryUsed[], SessionTime[] - foo} // Echo;
With[{$RL = $RecursionLimit},
  WithCleanup[ (* I hit the recursion limit the first time *)
   $RecursionLimit = 16*$RecursionLimit;
   Do[
    rt(*=roots[k]*)= iterFN[rt];
    DumpSave[tempfile, "rt"];
    Echo[k -> {MaxMemoryUsed[], MemoryInUse[], SessionTime[] - foo}],
    {k, 4}],
   $RecursionLimit = $RL]];
"Do" -> {MaxMemoryUsed[], SessionTime[] - foo} // Echo;
F[x, Log[x + rt], g] // N[#, 3] &
"F" -> MaxMemoryUsed[] // Echo;

SessionTime[] - foo
(*
>> M0->  224313792
>> Rt->{ 272925184,0.672463}
>> 1 ->{ 857442064,191757552,49.118817}
>> 2 ->{1605842208,233281752,141.129704}
>> 3 ->{2354243312,274805848,285.139376}
>> 4 ->{3102642584,316329952,491.884401}
>> Do->{3102642584, 491.919834}

0.*10^-500000073

>> F->7304699616

8503.749278
*)

Example: g = 10^10
I ran the above with g = 10^10. It computed the first iterate, which was saved in a .wl file of approximately 10GB. (Then I switched to .mx files, but I did not rerun the g = 10^10 trial, since it took several hours.) I killed the process and tested the root. When I tried to evaluate F[] at the approximate root, the kernel crashed (after some time), so I gave up.
Analysis
From the binomial theorem
$$\begin{align}
(x+\zeta)^{-g} &=x^{-g}-{g\over1}x^{-g-1}\zeta+{g\over1}{(g-1)\over2}x^{-g-2}\zeta^2+\cdots \\
\end{align}$$
we get the following linear approximations of the iterates:
$$
\begin{array}{}
z_0 &=& x^{-g} & =x^{-g} \\
z_1 &=& (x+x^{-g})^{-g} & \approx x^{-g} -{g \over x} x^{-2 g} \\
z_2 &=& (x+(x+x^{-g})^{-g})^{-g} & \approx x^{-g} -{g \over x} x^{-2 g} + \left({g \over x}\right)^2 x^{-3 g} \\
z_3 &=& (x+(x+(x+x^{-g})^{-g})^{-g})^{-g} & \approx x^{-g} -{g \over x}  x^{-2 g} + \left({g \over x}\right)^2 x^{-3 g} -\left({g \over x}\right)^3 x^{-4 g} \\
\vdots && \qquad \vdots & \approx \qquad \vdots \\
\end{array}
$$
Hence, one sees that $z_{n+1}-z_n \approx \left({g \over x}\right)^{n+1} x^{-ng}$. For $x=10$, we get approximately $g$ more digits of accuracy with each iteration. This has been verified numerically for $g=10^8$.
50-digit precision solutions
Quit[] before running each code to get a fresh kernel. As I have mentioned elsewhere, 50-digit approximates with $g=10^10$ are effectively computing Log[10], since the term Exp[-g*y] is too small to make a difference.
Easy way no. 1
ClearAll[F];
F[x_, y_, g_] := x - (Exp[y] - Exp[-g*y]);
wp = 50;
y0 = N[2*ArcSinh[x], wp]; (* pre-numericize numbers *)
x  = N[10, wp];
g  = N[10^10, wp];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
root = FindRoot[F[x, y, g], {y, y0}, WorkingPrecision -> wp, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*
98174480
{y -> 2.3025850929940456840179914546843642076011014886288}
98609568
*)

Easy way no. 2 (original answer)
ClearAll[F];
F[x_, y_?NumericQ, g_] := (* Prevent symbolic analysis *)
 x - (Exp[y] - Exp[-g*y]);
y0 = 2*ArcSinh[x];
x = 10;
g = 10^10;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
root = FindRoot[F[x, y, g], {y, y0}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
(*
97843152
{y -> 2.3025850929940456840179914546843642076011014886288}
98274600
*)

Monitoring memory usage
It seems that symbolic analysis may be the problem, although I haven't been able to exactly identify what is being done. Note that N[F[x, Log[10], g], 30] takes 16GB to calculate, which makes 10GB look relatively easy. The following shows that the 10GB is used in preprocessing before any step:
FindRoot[F[x, y, g], {y, y0}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
 EvaluationMonitor :>
  Echo[y -> {MaxMemoryUsed[], MemoryInUse[]}]
 ]


foo = SessionTime[];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
x = 10;
g = 10^10;
wp = 8;
root = FindRoot[x - (z - z^-g), {z, 10 + 1/10^(wp - 1)}
  , WorkingPrecision -> 10^wp, PrecisionGoal -> 30, 
  AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity],
  EvaluationMonitor :> 
   Echo[N[z, 50] -> {MaxMemoryUsed[], MemoryInUse[]}]]
MaxMemoryUsed[]
SessionTime[] - foo
(*
97836144
>> 10.000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000->{4499816624,222878608}
>> 10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000->{5288830656,970323784}
{z -> 10.`100000000.}
5288830656
220.805124
*)

Appendix
I first tried a different iteration and got some interesting errors. Like an invalid scaled vector norm constructed by Mathematica -- do you think that's a bug? And an infinite Divide[] with 4GB operands.


This seemingly simpler and equivalent system also uses 10GB: FindRoot[x - (z - z^-g), {z, Exp@y0}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 30, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]]

For such large $g$ I'd try a series-expansion of the root. In this case, the root is $y\approx\ln x+\frac{1}{x^{g+1}}$, which can be evaluated very quickly and has sufficient accuracy for you (I assume):
F[x_, y_, g_] = x - (Exp[y] - Exp[-g y]);
Y[x_, g_] = Log[x] + 1/(x^(g + 1));

Try it out for some smaller value of $g$:
With[{x = 10, g = 10^2},
  F[x, Y[x, g], g]] // N[#, 10^3] &
(*    -1.005`*^-199    *)

So it looks like the error is on the order of $x^{-2g}$, which I assume is sufficient for $g\sim10^{10}$.
Now, for $x=10$ and $g=10^{10}$ it is rather difficult to evaluate the resulting $y$ because it we need $10^{10}$ digits to show it accurately:
$$
y\approx\ln x+10^{-g-1}=\ln10+10^{-10\,000\,000\,001}
$$
which is very close to $\ln 10=2.30259\ldots$.
update: derivation
F[x_, y_, g_] = x - (Exp[y] - Exp[-g y]);

In the limit $g\to\infty$ we have a simpler equation
Assuming[x > 1 && y > 0, Limit[F[x, y, g], g -> ∞]]
(*    -E^y + x    *)

This asymptotic equation has a simple solution:
Assuming[x > 1, Solve[-E^y + x == 0, y, Reals]]
(*    {{y -> Log[x]}}    *)

Let's perturb this solution: assuming that for large (but finite) $g$ the solution changes only a little bit ε,
Series[F[x, Log[x] + ε, g], {ε, 0, 1}] // Normal // FullSimplify
(*    x^-g (1 - (g + x^(1 + g)) ε)    *)

This can be solved for ε to find the necessary correction due to the large (but finite) $g$:
Solve[x^-g (1 - (g + x^(1 + g)) ε) == 0, ε] // FullSimplify
(*    {{ε -> 1/(g + x^(1 + g))}}    *)

So we know that the solution is approximately
Y[x_, g_] = Log[x] + ε /. ε -> 1/(g + x^(1 + g));

We can continue this procedure and look for higher-order corrections. This is what AsymptoticSolve usually automates; but in this case it does not seem to work.

"which can be evaluated very quickly" -- Really??? Try it with the value of g the OP expressed interest in. It takes 85+ sec and 11+ GB to calculate the 4GB value. With g = 10^2, there's no trouble with FindRoot to begin with (it's fast, doesn't use a lot of memory). The math may be the same with a small or large g; but computationally it's different, and it seems that is what the OP is interested in.

@MichaelE2 If you want $10^{10}$ digits of the result, then it will take a while, of course. But that's true for any calculation and this one isn't special in any way. The OP only wants the final result for $y$ to a WorkingPrecision of 50 digits (and a PrecisionGoal of only 30 digits); and at that precision there's no need for the correction term, which is what I was showing with the given series expansion. If the OP wants less than $10^{10}$ digits, then N[Log[10], 100] (for example) is perfectly accurate and evaluate is superfast. As you showed in your answer.

"The OP only wants the final result for  to a WorkingPrecision of 50 digits" -- Right. So the term Exp[-g*y] may be neglected for g = 10^10. I see no practical point to solving the OP's specific equation numerically. Either they're confused (which I doubt) or they are asking for some other reason. The example equation is an MWE of some other behavior, which they felt was too complicated to post. This question appeared on Community, and that person is interested in very high precision.

@MichaelE2 yes what you say sounds right and the given problem looks like a MWE. The idea of series-expanding a root around an asymptote is generally a very useful technique and I wanted to recommend it to the OP quite generally to estimate deviations from an asymptote. Usually AsymptoticSolve can do this; but unfortunately the given example isn't solved automatically.

I noticed that about AsymptoticSolve[]. I was thinking of posting a fixed-point iteration that works quite nicely on this equation. I hesitate because I'm not sure anybody is interested in this equation.

Thank you guys, your comments are very interesting for me. But how do you know that for large g there is y = Log[x] + 1/x^(g+1) ? Is there any theory for this? I would appreciate any information that might be suitable for solving this equation, including the possible use of AsymptoticSolve[].  Leszek

@Leszek see update for how to derive the perturbation of the asymptotic solution.

@Leszek I updated my answer with an iterative approach.
